# Writing components in Storm using golang

Tags: go, apache-storm

I am interested in implementing a Storm topology with components written in Golang.
Basically “shelling” - creating topologies and implementing spouts and bolts in golang)

There is a project in git (https://github.com/jsgilmore/gostorm) which does something similar but I am not sure about it.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Has anybody used gostorm or any other way to run go code in storm